# Extract data from json object

Tags: json, excel, vba

I have Json that looks like
{"valid":"true","isinCode":null,"lastUpdateTime":"15-OCT-2012 14:18:56","tradedDate":"15OCT2012","data":[{"change":"16.75","lastPrice":"5,703.30"}

I've been able to extract this into a JSON object using a jsonlib.

How do i extract 'lastPrice' from this as its a nested json (data is another json object)?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing how your JSON library constructs the object in VBA.  Maybe you could show the relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use something like the below, it's quite specific to the JSON though, but light enough to re-jig everytime I need to parse new data:

```
Public Sub ReadJson()

    Const JsonString    As String = "{""valid"":""true"",""isinCode"":null,""lastUpdateTime"":""15-OCT-2012 14:18:56"",""tradedDate"":""15OCT2012"",""data"":[{""change"":""16.75"",""lastPrice"":""5,703.30""}]}"
    Dim objJson         As Object
    Dim objSE           As Object

    Set objSE = CreateObject("ScriptControl")

    With objSE
        .Language = "JScript"
        .AddCode "function getProp(jsonObj, propertyName) { return jsonObj[propertyName]; } "
        .AddCode "function getSubProp(jsonObj, pName, propertyName) { return jsonObj[pName][0][propertyName]; } "
    End With

    With objSE
        Set objJson = .Eval("(" + JsonString + ")")
        Debug.Print .Run("getProp", objJson, "valid")
        Debug.Print .Run("getProp", objJson, "isinCode")
        Debug.Print .Run("getProp", objJson, "lastUpdateTime")
        Debug.Print .Run("getProp", objJson, "tradedDate")
        Debug.Print .Run("getSubProp", objJson, "data", "change")
        Debug.Print .Run("getSubProp", objJson, "data", "lastPrice")
    End With

End Sub
```